# IPSuite Contact form error: Something went wrong. error code EX1

Tags: php, forms, apache, curl

I have IPSuite board 4.1 and as a guest i try to send message via contact form but i allways getting that wierd error:

> Something went wrong. Please try again. error code: EX1

and

> IPS\Http\Request\CurlException: Protocol "https" not supported or
>   disabled in libcurl (1)
>
> 0 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Http/Request/Curl.php(376):
>   IPS\Http\Request_Curl->_execute()
>
> 1 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Http/Request/Curl.php(276):
>   IPS\Http\Request_Curl->_executeAndFollowRedirects('POST', Array)
>
> 2
>   /home/mysite/public_html/system/Helpers/Form/Captcha/Recaptcha2.php(75):
>   IPS\Http\Request_Curl->post(Array)
>
> 3 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Helpers/Form/Captcha.php(110):
>   IPS\Helpers\Form\Captcha_Recaptcha2->verify()
>
> 4 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Helpers/Form/FormAbstract.php(158):
>   IPS\Helpers\Form_Captcha->getValue()
>
> 5 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Helpers/Form/FormAbstract.php(138):
>   IPS\Helpers\Form_FormAbstract->setValue(true)
>
> 6 [internal function]:
>   IPS\Helpers\Form_FormAbstract->__construct('captcha_field')
>
> 7 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Helpers/Form/Captcha.php(55):
>   call_user_func_array('parent::__const...', Array)
>
> 8
>   /home/mysite/public_html/applications/core/modules/front/contact/contact.php(51):
>   IPS\Helpers\Form_Captcha->__construct()
>
> 9 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Dispatcher/Controller.php(94): 
>   IPS\core\modules\front\contact_contact->manage()
>
> 10 /home/mysite/public_html/system/Dispatcher/Dispatcher.php(129): 
>   IPS\Dispatcher_Controller->execute()
>
> 11 /home/mysite/public_html/index.php(13): IPS_Dispatcher->run()
>
> 12 {main}

Now i thought the problem is on my **curl extension** but the curl extension **is enabled** on my apache server. Also, in my IPS ACP it have the "Mail delivery method" on PHP option selected.

I suspected ReCaptcha doing all the mess, and when i turn ReCaptcha off i get confirmed that my message was sent , **but** when i check my email for incoming messages i see nothing new.

Just cant sending messages via that **contact us** form.

How do i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on a security tweak settings:

The message was not leaving the server and actually being sent due to one of  configured Tweak Settings options. (RE: Mail sent by user nobody being discarded due to sender restrictions in WHM->Tweak Settings).

In WHM, i navigate to Home >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings [ Mail ]. And in the option labeled "Prevent “nobody” from sending mail", i switch from On, to Off and it was solved.

Now i can get messages again!